# Use tailwind properties directly in style html property

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

how can i use tailwindcss properties directly in style of html property?

```
function App() {

    return (
        <div style={'bg-gray-400 w-full h-screen p-10'}>
            <SideMenu />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

the above example is what i tried but `style={'bg-gray-400 w-full h-screen p-10'}` no works, i would like to use it inside style props or any js custom component to inject/modify the html.

Note: i know normally we use className to use tailwind css properties, but there are certains use cases when we have to use style properties to add css . framer-motion's variants is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the tailwind styles as a class, they don't need to be in the style tag. If it's not working I would make a whitelist somewhere that they can be compiled before this code executes.

```
<div class='bg-gray-400 w-full h-screen p-10'>
    <SideMenu />
</div>
```

Comment: As a mentioned in "note". what im asking is to add tailwind css into a style atribute no className. Framer motion variants requieres css into style and no classname. t

Comment: My bad! I must have missed that, upon closer look writing css in the style area is much like writing regular css, I haven't tested this but I would assume that to include tailwind css inline would be similar to using it in the style sheet and you might need to add their `@apply` before your styles. So I would try something like this `style={'@apply bg-gray-400 w-full h-screen p-10'}`

Comment: adding apply into style props doesnt work for tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible to use tailwind classes in style attributes. The properties and values the style attribute accepts are fixed values.